# <li> Steps with arrows

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make a HTML list with arrows between them (Something like: Step 1-2-3).

Here's a [wireframe](http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/51/02/f379008a71a95102.png) of the result i'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

I'm guessing that the icon and the content will be on a ul something like that:

```
<ul class="stepsCont"> 
  <li>
  <img src="icon" /> 
  <p>content</p>
  </li> 
</ul> 



.stepsCont li {display: inline; padding: 0 30px;}
```

But how to add the arrows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may insert the arrow as content image of a `:before` pseudoelement, starting from the second `<li>`, e.g.

```
li + li:before {
   content: url(arrow.png);
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0 30px;
}
```

or you could also add the arrow as a background

```
li + li  {
   background: url(arrow.png) center left no-repeat;
   padding-left: 50px;
}
```

**Codepen Example**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjCnA

*(Both the solution work even on `IE8`).*

Answer (score 2):

You can use **after** or **before** pseudonymes:

```
 .stepsCont li:after {
      content: ">";
      }

 .stepsCont li:last-child:after {
      display: none;
 }
```

Additional you can set here an Background image instead of `>`

Comment: using `li + li` has better support than `last-child`.  Plus it eliminates the need for an override.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using `:after`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6LtP/)

```
.stepsCont li {display: inline; padding: 0 30px;} 

/*Added code*/

li:after{
    content:" >";
}

li:last-of-type:after{
    content:"";
}
```

Then just style the `:after`.